# Converting PowerPoint Slides to Scorm 1.2

Tags: powerpoint, file-conversion, scorm

I have a Power Point presentation that I would like to convert to Scorm 1.2.  I have tried Adobe Captivate, however the videos within my presentation will not be Flash.  Adobe does not work with my files.  I have tried Scorm Hero.  The videos and gif images will not run.  Scorm Hero customer service says they do not support videos or gifs.  Can anyone suggest a good conversion tool for converting power point slides to SCORM 1.2 that will suppport gifs and videos?  Thank you.

Comment: What kind of videos are they? Anything that can be rendered in a browser can theoretically be converted to a SCORM package, but you'd have to get the content into a format that can be rendered by a browser first. You mention Power Point but then are talking about video files, are the videos embedded in Power Point slides? Does it have to be Power Point specifically or do you just need a slide deck?

Comment: Hi Brian.  The videos are mp4 videos.  I am creating an e-learning website and the videos and gifs are embedded in the Power Point slides.  It does have to be in power point as all of the slides are already prepared in Power Point.

Answer (score 0):

ScormHero now supports video conversions, just tested and is working fine. It also convert media (video or audio) from PowerPoint.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at any of the rapid development e-learning software out there. I believe Articulate 360 allows you to put a plugin directly into PPT to export out to SCORM compliant packages.

**Articulate**
https://articulate.com/360

I agree with your statement about Adobe Captivate, not really user friendly from a PPT perspective and pretty pricy.